# Inserting a page after title page containing text and image without numbering

Tags: page-breaking

How can I insert a new page containing text and image (so I would be able to edit that page) after my title page and before ToC without counting that page in a multi-file format?

thanks a bunch,

Here are the main.tex , Title.tex , Preamble.sty

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{Preamble}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{10pt}   {\LARGE\bfseries}

\begin{document}


\import{./}{Title.tex} 


\afterpage{
\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\chapter{text}
\import{Sections/}{Section1-1.tex}

\chapter{text}
\import{Sections/}{Section2-1.tex}

\chapter{text}
\import{Sections/}{Section3-1.tex}


\import{./}{Bibliography.tex}

\end{document}
```

Title.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}

    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.57\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{titlepic1}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

    \vspace{2cm}

    \textbf{\LARGE{text}}


    \vspace{2cm}


    \textbf{text}\\

    \vspace{1cm}
    17/06/2016\\
    text

    \vspace{5cm}

    \begin{flushright}
    text
    \end{flushright}

    \vfill



\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Preamble.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{Preamble}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[innercaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait}
\geometry{top=20mm, left=20mm, right=20mm, footskip=50pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\small{text}}
```

Comment: Is that for a one-side or two-side document? If the latter, please don't do stuff like that, it completely messes things up.

Comment: In a well typeset document, every page is counted, if pages that are empty.

Comment: \thispagestyle{empty} won't show the number, although the page counter will still increment.   \setcounter{page}{0} will make the next page 1.

Comment: my document class is \documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twoside]{report}, so there is no way that I can have a page with text after title and before contents page?

Comment: @Dude: Of course you have a page after title and before `ToC`, with any text you desire

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, How can I do this please?

Comment: @Dude: Provide a compilable, minimal version of your document with titlepage, toc etc. I don't want to start with guess work based on class `A` or class `B` etc.

Comment: Ok, first off: I am using a multi-file format, meaning I have a separate files as: Title.tex , Main.tex , Preamble.sty , bibliography.tex and seperate forlders for images and sections.

Comment: Well here is my main.tex
`\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{Preamble}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{10pt}{\LARGE\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\import{./}{Title.tex} 

\afterpage{
\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\chapter{text}
\import{Sections/}{Section1-1.tex}

\chapter{text}
\import{Sections/}{Section2-1.tex}

\chapter{text}
\import{Sections/}{Section3-1.tex}
\import{./}{Bibliography.tex}
\end{document}`

Comment: Here is my Preamble.sty
`\ProvidesPackage{Preamble}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\small{text}}`

Comment: And finally Title.tex
`\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        
        \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.57\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{titlepic1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
 \textbf{\LARGE{text}}
        \vspace{2cm}
        \textbf{text}\\
        
        \vspace{1cm}
        17/06/2016\\
        text
\begin{flushright}
        \text
        \end{flushright}
 \end{center}
\end{titlepage}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, sorry for the messy code, couldn't do it better than this, 
Although if you also tell me how to upload a code block within a comment properly I would be grateful.
cheers

Comment: @Dude: Hm, what do you think the `edit` button below your post is meant for? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, so you need me to provide the code in another way? or you think it would be possible to help me with this messy one?!
Thanks

Comment: @Dude: Just put the whole stuff together in your post,not as comments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, It looks better now I guess :) sorry for being a total noob

Comment: Sorry, nobody gave you a link so far: [Providing a minimal compilable example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html)

Comment: Using `\subfigure` on the titlepage is very strange, very strange. On the other hand, naming a package `preamble` is even more strange.

Comment: @Johannes_B, about the `\subfigure`it's because I had originally two figures in the title page, but here there is just one left. I have to admit that the code that you are seeing here is an old code that I used for another report and now I am reusing it by restructuring it. so some of the syntaxes are left from before even though there is no use for them in the new report. As long as they are not disturbing the process I just leave them there.